# Set div data-src url from server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to know is there any way to assign url to data-src in a div in HTML5 from server side as I fetch images from database in asp.net? Like there are 2 `div` with attribute `data-src` in the given code. Now i want to assign those images from server side as images fetching from the database.

```
        <div data-src="eventcss/images/slide.jpg">
            <div class="caption fadeIn">
                <h2>Cricket</h2>
                <div class="price" >
                    FROM
                    <span>10 am</span>
                </div>
                <a href="#">See Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="checkdiv" runat="server">
            <div class="caption fadeIn">
                <h2>Football</h2>
                <div class="price">
                    FROM
                    <span>2 pm</span>
                </div>
                <a href="#">See Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I try to find the solution on google. But nothing relevant material is found.
It will be great help to me if any one guide me. Thanks

Comment: You can by using client side scripting or constructing your HTML on the server side.

Comment: @Oluwafemi as you can see in the 2nd `div` i try to make it `runat="server" `. But the `data-src` attribute is not being accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a couple of properties in the code behind > set their values > and finally call them from the design with to populate the `data-src` attribute.

**Code behind:**

```
public string Div1 { get; set; }
public string Div2 { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Div1 = "eventcss/images/slide.jpg";
    Div2 = "eventcss/images/slide2.jpg";
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<div id="div1" data-src='<%: Div1 %>'>
</div>
<div id="div2" data-src='<%: Div2 %>'>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly as I have it?What is not working?A div is not an image, it will not set the background of the div to the image you are passing through, setting `data-src` will simply set the src attribute TEXT to the value that you pass through

Comment: it pass the value of the string but with single quotes like this `'eventcss/images/slide.jpg'` where the the required string is in double quotes `"eventcss/images/slide.jpg"`

Comment: Look at the Output in my answer.When the HTML is rendered in the browser it will be double quotes.Everything is working fine

Comment: but not in my case i tried it many times. I also pass the value to a label to check whether the value is accessible or not, the label shows the value but when i pass the value to `data-src` no picture is displayed.

Comment: now its working. I remove the `runat="server"`attribute and now it displays the picture :)